# What is the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $ z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and the plane $z=10 $?

Tags: volume

I want calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $ z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and the plane $z=10,$ using double integral in cartesian coordinate system.

**My approach:**

Putting $ \ z=10 \ $, we get the circle $ \ x^{2}+y^{2}=10 .$ Then the volume $$V= \int_{-\sqrt {10}}^{\sqrt  {10}} \int_{-\sqrt{10}}^{\sqrt{10}} (x^{2}+y^{2}-10)dxdy.$$

**Is it right ?  Any help is really appreciating?**

Comment: I don't understand how you set up the integral. Firstly, $z=10$ is on top. Second, the projection onto the $xy$ plane is a circle not a $2\sqrt{10}$ by $2\sqrt{10}$ rectangular region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The projection onto the $xy$ plane of your solid of interest is the disk given by $x^2+y^2 \leq 10$. As you noted the outline was $x^2+y^2=10$.

As such we let $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 \leq 10 \}$. Then we integrate the height of our solid over the region $D$ to find the volume of our solid. Because $z=10$ is the upper portion of our solid, the height is $10-(x^2+y^2)=10-x^2-y^2$.

The volume is thus,

$$V=\iint_{D} (10-x^2-y^2) dA$$

---

In rectangular coordinates first integrating over $x$ then $y$:

$$=\int_{-\sqrt{10}}^{\sqrt{10}} \int_{-\sqrt{10-y^2}}^{\sqrt{10-y^2}} (10-x^2-y^2) dx dy$$

---

In rectangular coordinates the other way:

$$=\int_{-\sqrt{10}}^{\sqrt{10}} \int_{-\sqrt{10-x^2}}^{\sqrt{10-x^2}} (10-x^2-y^2) dy dx$$

---

In polar coordinates:

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{10}} (10-r^2) r dr d\theta$$

Answer (score 4):

For any $w\in[0,10]$, the area of the section $z=w$ is $\pi w$. By [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) it follows that the wanted volume is $\int_{0}^{10}\pi w\,dw = \color{red}{50\pi}$.

Comment: I need to formulate the volume using double integral and cartesian coordinate

Comment: @mabmath: why do you *need* an involved approach when there is a simple and effective one?